# Flask ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-applications, google-colaboratory

The model consists of 2 features (longitude and latitude) and performs single-label regression.

When I enter the values of longitude and latitude on the web and hit the Predict button, an interval server error occurs.

`Python version: 3.6.9`
`Flask version: 1.1.2`

```
Code:

"""
Initialize the server by creating Flask class object
Name the app as app

"""
app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the ML model as pickle file
file = open('regr.pkl', 'rb')
model = load(file)

# Run web-app on a VM
run_with_ngrok(app) 

# Define web pages using decorator
@app.route('/')
def home(): 
    return render_template('index.html')

# Decorator to use the 'Predict' button in our web-app
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    """
    An inference app named 'predict' that
    renders results on HTML GUI and 
    retrieves values from the form with
    function parameters specified as float datatype

    """

    init_features = [float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [array(init_features)]
    print(len(final_features))
    
    # Make prediction
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)
    output = round(prediction[0], 2) 
    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text=f'The Midpoint of X could be: {output}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

HTML:

```
%%writefile templates/index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

 <head>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>MPX Predictor</title>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="description" content="A Scikit-Learn-based ML model that predicts the midpoint of X">

   <!-- Render correctly on mobile devices -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">

   <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
   <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
   <meta name="application-name" content="MPX Predictor">
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#303F9F">

   <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="MPX Predictor">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#303F9F">

   <!-- Tile icon for Win8 -->
   <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">
   <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#303F9F">
   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-135532366-1"></script>
   <script>function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[], gtag("js", new Date), gtag("config", "UA-135532366-1");</script>

   <!-- Web Application Manifest -->
   <link rel="manifest" href='data:application/manifest+json, { "name": "MPX Predictor", "short_name": "MPX Predictor", "display": "standalone" }' media="screen /> 

   <!-- Master CSS and JS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons", media="screen">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.orange-indigo.min.css" media="screen">
   <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

 </head>

   <body>
  
    <!-- Fixed header -->
    <div style="margin: 40px;" class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-color-text--white mdl-color--indigo-700">

        <!-- Grid -->
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-grid">
          <div class="mdl-layout__header-row mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop"">
            <h3> MPX Predictor </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <h4> Predict the Midpoint of X </h4>
      <h5> Enter the following values to predict the Midpoint of X </h5>

     <!-- Numeric textfields with floating label -->
      <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}" method="post">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
           <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" style="height: 25px;" name="X1" id="long" required="required" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?">
           <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="long">Longitude</label>
        </div>
            
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
           <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" style="height: 25px;" name="X1" id="lat" required="required" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?">
           <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="lat">Latitude</label>
        </div>

          <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
          <button type="submit" style="margin: 15px;" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">Predict</button>
      </form>

      <br>
      <br>
      
      {{ prediction_text }} 

    </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

```
Complete traceback:

 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Running on http://9becd2f4e911.ngrok.io
 * Traffic stats available on http://127.0.0.1:4040
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2020 19:28:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2020 19:28:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[2020-10-22 19:28:18,533] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "<ipython-input-22-28ae2839ef41>", line 37, in predict
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py", line 116, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 419, in predict
    Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tpot/builtins/stacking_estimator.py", line 93, in transform
    X_transformed = np.hstack((np.reshape(self.estimator.predict(X), (-1, 1)), X_transformed))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 225, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 209, in _decision_function
    dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 151, in safe_sparse_dot
    ret = a @ b
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2020 19:28:18] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Link to the Colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jVRhIZEV8rjdsQFPvWJof9R7wJcdF-cd?usp=sharing

The length of `final_features` is 1 while the number of fitted features should be 2, which is causing the error. How to feed both features to the predict function?

Comment: Please paste the complete traceback and the relevant code into the question.

Comment: @zvone check now.

Comment: There is a difference between "relevant code" and "all code". Anyway... The traceback shows one line from your code: `prediction = model.predict(final_features)`. So, most probably, what you are sending in as `final_features` is not valid.

Comment: @zvone I already wrote that the mismatch is occurring due to final_features, that's why I'm asking for a fix.